# Check sizes for a groups of folders (grouped by some pattern)

Tags: bash

I have a folder which contains many other folders, but they are always with some suffixes fox example test.folder-1-2-3 and test.folder-1-2-4 ..there are always more folders with the same suffix and I would like to count sizes of all folders of the same suffix and count this for all suffixes. 
I made this. I created array where all suffixes are stored and then in for cycle I am perfoming the du command to check the size for each suffix and then use awk to sum it.
Unfortunately it takes hours and hours so it is unusable for me..
Any suggestions how to do this faster?
Thanks,

```
list=($(ls /folder/where/others/are | grep "folder.which.exists.for.all.suffixes" | sort -u | cut --delimiter="-" -f5-9)); 

echo ${list[@]};

for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#list[@]} ; i++ ));
do
temp=${list[$i]}
echo Currently checking for size of all folder containing: $temp
du -s /folder/where/others/are |grep $temp |awk '{sum +=$1};END {print "Total size is:" sum*512 "[B]" }'
```

done

Answer (score 0):

To sum sizes of all dirs with suffix `$suf`:

```
find . -type d -name "*$suf" | xargs du  | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd+ - |  bc
```

Comment: It is still horribly slow and I am still waiting for result. I wish there was faster way, anyhow thanks so much.

Comment: How much does it take to run `du` in the root of your directories? If it is horribly slow, then it is not the script's fault, but probably you have horribly lots of directories and files

Comment: Well only simple du is running 1:29h in the directory I need. I know there are many folders, files, but that is why I need to see it time to time. The script I made was running for almost 10hours and did just like 30% of "suffixes"...

Comment: After all I ran the simple du -s on the whole folder with outputting into text file and then I counted the sizes in text files.

    for file in `ls /folder/i/want/`
    do
    du -s /folder/i/want/$file | tee -a /tmp/lest.txt
    done

    list=($(ls /folder/i/want/| grep "pattern.i.need" | sort -u | cut --delimiter="-" -f5-9)); 
    echo ${list[@]};
    for (( i = 0 ; i < ${#list[@]} ; i++ ));
    do
    echo Currently checking for size of all folder containing: ${list[$i]}
    temp=${list[$i]}
    grep $temp$ /tmp/list.txt |awk '{sum +=$1};END {print "Total size is:" sum/1024/1024 "[GB]" }'